# Static Strings in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class with some static information, i.e:

```
public static class MyApp
{
    public static string Name = "Awesome App";
    public static string Version = "1.0";
}
```

I want anywhere in my application that displays the App's name to use this string, the problem I have is in a few places there's more than variable string.

So for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="Awesome App running version 1.0"/>
```

I want this to populate from the static variables. I have done some reading and see a couple of options:

### 1. Using a `MultiBinding` and loading in the relevant `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <sys:String x:Key="AppName">Awesome App</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="AppVersion">1.0</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>

<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} running version {1}">
            <Binding Path="{StaticResource AppName}"/>
            <Binding Path="{StaticResource AppVersion}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I guess I could also have multiple `TextBlock`s too:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AppName}"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" running version "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AppVersion}"/>
<TextBlock>
```

### 2. Use a static "strings" class with static properties:

```
public static class Strings
{
    public static string ProductRunningVersion =>
        $"{MyApp.Name} running version {MyApp.Version}";
}

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Strings.ProductRunningVersion}"/>
```

The use of `=>` in the property is intentional - when testing I was having issues with the initialization order of some of my static variables. (Some are initialized through a static constructor)

---

I'm not sure which approach is better.
Approach one feels more "proper" but also very messy.
Approach two feels a lot cleaner but less typical to what I'm use to with WPF. Also having to define the strings as `get` functions rather than a static string costs somewhat?

Are either of these approaches any good? I'm not really after localisation, more to change the name and a few images throughout the app.

Comment: 1st approach is better as it is logical and is pure markup based. And replace inner `TextBlocks` with `Run` in your next sub-approach in 1st approach.

Answer (score 3):

All of the approaches are valid. Use what works best for you. I do have a couple of comments:

- You don't have to add the strings to a `ResourceDictionary`; you can use `x:Static` to access constants as well:

  ```
  <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} running version {1}">
              <Binding Source="{x:Static local:MyApp.Name}"/>
              <Binding Source="{x:Static local:MyApp.Version}"/>
          </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
  ```
- A `TextBlock` uses `Inline`s (which is a *lightweight* content element) to render text, the most basic of which is a `Run`. If you want to build a complex `TextBlock`, you should use those, and not add other `TextBlock`s (which are full-fledged controls). So, to use your example:

  ```
  <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="{x:Static local:MyApp.Name}"/>
      <Run Text=" running version "/>
      <Run Text="{x:Static local:MyApp.Version}"/>
  <TextBlock>
  ```

  I would prefer this approach to the `MultiBinding`. Here, for example, you can even add elements such as `<Bold>` and `<Hyperlink>` to render formatted text.

Comment: +1. A `TextBlock` with `Runs` is the best, simplest and clearest solution, and can even be shortened, since raw text elements inside TextBlocks are automatically treated as Runs:
`<TextBlock><Run Text="{x:Static local:MyApp.Name}"/> running <Run Text="{x:Static local:MyApp.Version}"/>`